# CRM 2011 - Duplicate Detection while saving using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a javascript which uses OData and Creates a record in PhoneCall entity.
I have Subject attribute of this PhoneCall entity which need to be unique.
I read about "SuppressDuplicateDetection" parameter in following link -
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh210213.aspx

How can I leverage this parameter inside my OData call?

Here's my javascript code -

```
var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + '/XRMServices/2011/OrganiationData.svc/PhoneCallSet'
$.ajax
({
    type:"POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    url: serverUrl,
    data: phoneCallData,
    beforeSend: function(xhr)
    {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    success: function (data, textSTatus, XmlHttpRequest)
    {
        //my success LOC
    },
    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textSTatus, errorThrown)
    {
        //error handler
    },
    async: false
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really sad to say this: No way to use `SuppressDuplicateDetection` option with odata on client side.

> we need the CreateRequest to enable Dup detection while creating record and therefore this feature is not available when creating records using oData.

Ref: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2014/07/21/duplicate-detection-is-back-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-spring-release

Comment: What I did was - create a new field for this entity
Then, I went on to create a Unique Index over this newly created field in the Database. I put a Null Qualifier for the Index to apply
From my javascript, I populate the value for this field with a value which I consider to be unique. So, in case for any reason of concurrency, this call gets called twice, the database will prevent duplicate entry of record.

it wrks!